# How to effectively eliminate stringing in 3D print

Tags: ultimaker-cura, 3d-models, troubleshooting, creality-ender-3

I'm having this stringing problem that happens when the machine moves and when it's not supposed to print that I still haven't effectively solved. I will try exemplify with the following image.

[image]

We can see it leaves some prints when it's not supposed to.

I know we can try to solve it with the retraction properties, but is there a way to calculate the right levels of it?

How do you guys do it?

My setup is:

- Ender3 printer
- Ultimaker Cura sw
- BQ filament

Info about this particular filament, from store.bq.com

**DIMENSIONS AND WEIGHT**

- Weight - 1 kg
- Filament diameter - 1.75 mm
- Coil size (diameter x width) - 175 x 77 mm
- Spool axle diameter - 44 mm
- Enclosure - 187 x 187 x 83 mm

**MATERIAL**

- Composition - 100% PLA (Polylactic acid).

**PRINTING FEATURES**

- Optimum printing temperature - 205 ºC
- Printing temperature range - 200-220 ºC

Comment: Add which material you are printing to your question by [edit]. Is this PETG? PETG is known for its stringing properties and is hard to completely get rid of. I've printed kilometers of 2.85 mm PETG and have reduced stringing to a minimum, but some models still show very fine strings.

Comment: Now that the image has changed, this question has turned in a "help me fight stringing" which has been asked [multiple times](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/search?q=Stringing). Please look into other questions and answers and try to define what is different to your situation. E.g. those very fine strings are common  for PETG.

Comment: This is getting confusing, due to the image change and probably should be closed as a duplicate now (unless the image gets reverted back and the question edited to address the issue in the original question). However, close it as a duplicate against which question, as there are a number to chose from?

Comment: @Greenonline sorry i could only provide the info now. The problem is that when i created the post i didnt had the right image to provide, but i said it on parentesis.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the update. Yeah, it is true you did state that in the parentheses. Just out of interest, w.r.t. the original image, were those random thick orthogonal lines intentional?

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** The image in the question was changed after the question was asked. This answer is out-of-date with respect to how the question has changed; I'll update it when more information is available.

---

These don't look like strings, which I'd define as material deposited outside of the model, but rather damage done by moving the hotend through already-printed material without retracting. In Cura, this is called "retraction combing", and it defaults to "all", which is way too aggressive and visibly harms the surface finish. Switching it to "noskin" or even "infill" only will make this go away and greatly improve your print quality, at the cost of some speed. The cost can be severe in worst case with certain kinds of fine detail, but usually "noskin" is cheap and suffices.

Comment: OK, this new image looks completely different from the old one and largely invalidates my answer. I may update it later.

Comment: Thanks, that might be another problem, I switched to an image where I show the stringing that is happening

Comment: You should reply to Oscar's comment asking about the material, and provide as much information as you can about your settings.

Comment: @Nmaster88 - IMHO, I think you should revert the image, via a roll back, and let this answer answer the original question, as it is a little unfair to change the question after someone has taken the time to answer it. Meanwhile, check the other stringing questions (provided by 0scar's link above) to see if they address your issue and if not, post an new different question. It's just a suggestion, but seems to make sense, given the current situation.